# UINavigationBar disappears after dismissing mail from UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm using `UIActivityViewController` to display a share functionality with email and messages, however if I cancel the mail in the view controller that popped up, the navigation bar of the presenting view controller is gone. I only do this in the method to show the `UIActivityViewController`:

```
UIActivityViewController *shareController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[UIActivityTypeMail, UIActivityTypeMessage] applicationActivities:nil];
shareController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToTwitter, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard];

[self.navigationController presentViewController:shareController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And in viewWillAppear, I have that:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:YES];
  self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue with setting the hidden property of the navigation bar to NO inside the completion block of dismissViewController.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:YES];
  [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow I had the same problem - after my `UIActivityViewController` dismissed, one of my `UIView`s would "disappear" and have a different weird frame. Then I realized that it was because my `UIView` subclass for the disappearing view had set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`, whereas I was not using Autolayout, so it should have been `true`:

```
self.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)
```

In short, make sure your "disappearing" view does not think it is using constraints if it's not.

Comment: I'm using autolayout. Any idea how to handle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you presenting it correctly?
Taken from the documentation:

> When presenting the view controller, you must do so using the
>   appropriate means for the current device. On iPad, you must present
>   the view controller in a popover. On iPhone and iPod touch, you must
>   present it modally.

Comment: `presentModalViewController` is deprecated in iOS 6.0, instead you should use `presentViewController:animated` like I do